# Django: How can I reverse objects with DetailView?

Tags: python-3.x, django, sqlite, django-templates, django-generic-views

I have used generic views. Every Episode is connected to a certain season through `ForeignKey`. In `views.py` I have these:

```
class SeasonList(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'episodes/episodes.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_seasons'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return reversed(Season.objects.all())

# Here I need to sort the episodes     
class SeasonDetails(generic.DetailView):
    model = Season
    template_name = 'episodes/season_details.html'
```

In the list view I used `reversed()` to show the latest season first. Similarly, in the detail view, I want the episodes to appear in the descending order because the latest episode should appear at the top of the page.

In my html I have accessed the episodes list using `season.episode_set.all`

```
    {% for episode in season.episode_set.all %}

       <!-- the tags to show the list -->

    {% endfor %}
```

Is there any way how I can reverse the episode list?

Answer (score 2):

You could order by `id` and use descendant `-` or ascendant depending on your need

```
Season.objects.all().order("id") # Ascendant

Season.objects.all().order("-id") # Decendant
```

Or `reverse()` will be ok to reverse the queryset whatever your filter.

```
Season.objects.all().reverse()
```

Comment: But it will reverse the objects of seasons. I've already done it. Actually I'm looking for a way that would reverse the episodes. I used foreign key to connect the episodes with a certain season.

Sorry if I failed to describe my problem properly.

Answer (score 0):

To sort the episodes, you can use something like this -

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['episodes'] = Episodes.objects.all().order_by('-date_posted')
    return context
```